# Moderators Pro Tempore - now served late!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Craig Constantine]
[image: YLearn]
[image: Mike Pennington]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: lol, I misread the title as latté when I first saw this. Confusion ensued. But, that would be an awesome perk.

Comment: Can we nominate someone?  @ytti

Comment: @generalnetworkerror: not at this point, but if/when this site graduates and we hold elections, folks will be able to nominate themselves.

Comment: instead of "you'll have your elections in several weeks" shouldn't that be "you'll have your elections in [six to eight weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/160519 "six to eight weeks")"?

Comment: Did I miss the elections or are the moderators still pro temp a year after this post?

Comment: No elections yet, @generalnetworkerror