# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Network Engineering's [first moderator election](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: YLearn] [image: Craig Constantine] [image: Teun Vink]

They've replaced [the pro-tempore crew](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/moderators-pro-tempore-now-served-late)<sup>*</sup> — please thank **both** teams for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new crew as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6379812587307008/0).

<sup>*"augmented" may be a better word here...</sup>

Comment: First-ever elected moderators, congrats!  It's good to see that folks are happy with the pro-tempore moderation styles.  Keep up the great work.  Teun, congratulations and enjoy the stay.  You've earned it and we look forward to having you take care of this stack.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks all for putting your trust in us